# Perl - problems to validate a param in a for loop

Tags: perl, for-loop

The script catch 5x2 input fields.

```
for ($i=0;$i<6;$i++) {

   $zeit_[$i] = $q->param("zeit_[$i]");
   $tatigkeit_[$i] = $q->param("tatigkeit_[$i]");

   ##validation

   if (!$zeit_[1]) 
      {&error('Bitte geben Sie mindestens eine Aktivität an!');}
   if ($zeit_[$i] =~ /\D/) 
      {&error('Die Zeitangabe zur Aktivität "'. $tatigkeit_[$i] . '"enthält ein unzulässiges Zeichen! Bitte geben Sie nur ganze Zahlen an!');}
   if ($tatigkeit_[$i] =~ /[^A-Za-z0-9öäüÖÄÜß-\s]/) 
      {&error('Die Tätigkeit "' . $tatigkeit_[$i] . '" enthält ein unzulässiges Zeichen!');}

   #prepare the output
   if ($zeit_[$i]) {$ausgabe.= $zeit_[$i] . " mit " . $tatigkeit_[$i] . " ID: $i<br>";}

}
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print $ausgabe; exit();
```

My problem is this validation (the first input must be filled):

```
if (!$zeit_[1]) 
  {&error('Bitte geben Sie mindestens eine Aktivität an!');}
```

The validation subroutine `error` occurs in all cases. Empty input and also with one or all five inputs filled.

When I negatively the validation into

```
if ($zeit_[1]) 
  {&error('Bitte geben Sie mindestens eine Aktivität an!');}
```

the `error` occurs also. I think the problem ist the var `$zeit_[1]`

When I disable the validation with `#` - the script works fine. The output show all 10 elements.

May somebody a tip for me?

## This update fixed the problem

Changed `for ($i=0;$i<6;$i++)` into `for ($i=1;$i<6;$i++)`. Right code:

```
for ($i=1;$i<6;$i++) {

   $zeit_[$i] = $q->param("zeit_[$i]");
   $tatigkeit_[$i] = $q->param("tatigkeit_[$i]");

   ##validation

   if (!$zeit_[1]) 
     {&error('Bitte geben Sie mindestens eine Aktivität an!');}
   if ($zeit_[$i] =~ /\D/) 
     {&error('Die Zeitangabe zur Aktivität "'. $tatigkeit_[$i] . '"enthält ein unzulässiges Zeichen! Bitte geben Sie nur ganze Zahlen an!');}
   if ($tatigkeit_[$i] =~ /[^A-Za-z0-9öäüÖÄÜß-\s]/) 
     {&error('Die Tätigkeit "' . $tatigkeit_[$i] . '" enthält ein unzulässiges Zeichen!');}

   #prepare the output
   if ($zeit_[$i]) {$ausgabe.= $zeit_[$i] . " mit " . $tatigkeit_[$i] . " ID: $i<br>";}

}
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print $ausgabe; exit();
```

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Your `for` loop goes from 0 to 5, which is 6 iterations. Maybe you mean `for( $i = 0; $i < 5; $i++ )`

Comment: `for( $i = 0; $i < 5; $i++ )`  is for 4 elements. I have 5. The  `$i<5`  means 1 to 4

Comment: @Club: `for (  $i = 0; $i < 5; $i++ )` is `0 .. 4` which is five elements. If you really mean `1 .. 4` then write `for my $i ( 1 .. 4 )` but remember that array indices are zero-based.

Comment: A better way to write your corrected `for` loop is: `for my $i (1 .. 5)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that this is a simple typo. But you don't show us the input data you're expecting so it's impossible to do anything other than guess.

(I'm also guessing that this is a CGI program written using CGI.pm - it would be better if you could point that out in your question.)

Inside your validation, you have:

```
if (!$zeit_[1])
```

But on other validation lines, you have:

```
if ($zeit_[$i] =~ /\D/)
```

It doesn't seem to make sense to check `$zeit_[1]` in one case and `$zeit_[$i]` in the others. In any case, `$zeit_[1]` is not going to be set on the first iteration of the loop (where `$i` is 0 and therefore `$zeit_[1]` won't have been given a value yet).

A couple of other Perl tips:

- `for ($i=0;$i<6;$i++)` is far easier to understand if you write it as `for my $i (0 .. 5)`.
- There is no need to use `&` on subroutine calls. `error(...)` works just as well as `&error(...)` (and has the bonus of not confusing non-Perl programmers).
- If you're using CGI.pm (and the calls to `$q->param(...)` imply that you are) then you can use `$q->header(...)` to create the CGI header.

**Update:** Taking into account everything we've learned, I'd write it more like this:

```
for my $i (0 .. 5) {

  $zeit_[$i] = $q->param("zeit_[$i]");
  $tatigkeit_[$i] = $q->param("tatigkeit_[$i]");

  ##validation

  if ($i == 1 and !$zeit_[$i]) {
    error('Bitte geben Sie mindestens eine Aktivität an!');
  }

  if ($zeit_[$i] =~ /\D/) {
    # Interpolate variables in double-quoted strings
    error("Die Zeitangabe zur Aktivität '$tatigkeit_[$i]' enthält ein unzulässiges Zeichen! Bitte geben Sie nur ganze Zahlen an!");
  }

  if ($tatigkeit_[$i] =~ /[^A-Za-z0-9öäüÖÄÜß-\s]/) {
    error("Die Tätigkeit '$tatigkeit_[$i]' enthält ein unzulässiges Zeichen!");
  }

  #prepare the output
  if ($zeit_[$i]) {
    $ausgabe.= "$zeit_[$i] mit $tatigkeit_[$i] ID: $i<br>";
  }
}

print $q->header;
print $ausgabe;
exit();
```

Comment: `if (!$zeit_[1]) `is the validation for "the first input" must be filled. If this is correct then check the value with `if ($zeit_[$i] =~ /\D/) `. I´ve perl self-educated - so on I have to learn a lot. Thanks

Comment: @ClubCola: You probably don't want to test `$zeit_[1]` each time round the loop then.